# Odd fields in my objects on the Web Service Client Side

Tags: c#, wcf

I have object, something like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Something
{
   [DataMember]
   public string One { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Two { get; set; }
}
```

I have the Web Service which return the List.  If I debug the value of List elements on the Web Service - they look fine.

But if I debug the value which was returned by my Web Service on the Web Client I can see that all Something objects have additional fields OneField (which value equal One) and TwoField (which value is equal Two).

Here is client code:

```
ServiceReference.WebServiceClient proxy = new ServiceReference.WebServiceClient();

ServiceReference.Something[] somethings = proxy.GetSomethings();
foreach (ServiceReference.Something something in somethings)
{
   // inspect something variable here
}
```

I am just wondering what is the reason of this additional fields?  Can I do something if I don't want to have them in the client side?

Comment: `One` and `Two` are properties. Private fields **must** exist.

Comment: It's just the way the tool has scaffolded the proxy classes, it has created backing fields for your properties rather than using automatic properties because i think it puts extra logic in the accessors of the proxy classes that fire events and stuff.  It has no impact on any code using the classes as they are private fields.